# Can't delete the tr element of the table. JS

Tags: javascript

I have the functionality of dynamically added / removed input. The addition works fine, but the removal does not want to work. I found a jQuery implementation of this functionality and tried to convert it to pure JS. This is how the deletion is implemented (I tested it on jQuery and it works on it).

```
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
   $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

```js
var i = '2';
document.getElementById('addRow').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="inputFormRow">';
          html += '<td id="prevdel">'+i+'</td>';
          html += '<td>';
            html += '<input type="text" name="position_name[]" placeholder="Enter new position">';
          html += '</td>';
          html += '<td>';
            html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
              html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
            html += '</div>';
          html += '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        //
        i++;

        // document.getElementById('newRow').append(html);
        document.getElementById('newRow').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
    });

  // remove row
  document.getElementById('removeRow').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('prevdel').previousSibling.remove();
  });
  //
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="POST">
          <table class="table table-success table-striped w-75 text-center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            <div id="inputFormRow">
              <td>1
              </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="position_name[]" value="Some data">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
                      <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </div>
            </tr>
             <tr id="newRow"></tr>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                 <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
               </td>
             </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: If ever there was a time to learn about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) now would be it =) Don't use `html += ...; html += ...; html += ....'`, just have a single ```html = `.......`;``` instruction, and you can have as many newlines in there as you like.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about it, thanks! However, deletion still doesn't work)))

Comment: You can't repeat element IDs in a  page. Think of them like an address. Use classes instead

Comment: It will still pick the first nearest id, right? This is what I need to delete.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Why do you say that, it's just a string being contenated, I think, you think of `innerHTML`, where your argument certainly holds.

Comment: No, I'm not. You should never need string concatenation in modern code. Especially given how many bugs string concatenation gave rise to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery version is using *event delegation* to account for elements that don't exist at run time

You can do the same thing by adding the event listener to the table and checking the `event target`

```
document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click', function (e){
   if(e.target.matches('button.removeRow')){
      e.target.closest('tr').remove()
   }      
});
```

Working version - Note I changed the two remove button id to class

```js
var i = '2';
document.getElementById('addRow').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="inputFormRow">';
          html += '<td id="prevdel">'+i+'</td>';
          html += '<td>';
            html += '<input type="text" name="position_name[]" placeholder="Enter new position">';
          html += '</td>';
          html += '<td>';
            html += '<div class="input-group-append ml-3">';
              html += '<button  type="button" class="removeRow btn btn-danger">Delete</button>';
            html += '</div>';
          html += '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        //
        i++;

        // document.getElementById('newRow').append(html);
        document.getElementById('newRow').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
    });

  // remove row
  document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click', function (e){
     if(e.target.matches('button.removeRow')){
        e.target.closest('tr').remove()
     }
      
  });
  //
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="" method="POST">
          <table class="table table-success table-striped w-75 text-center">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
            <div id="inputFormRow">
              <td>1
              </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="position_name[]" value="Some data">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group-append ml-3">
                      <button  type="button" class="removeRow btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </div>
            </tr>
             <tr id="newRow"></tr>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                 <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Add field</button>
               </td>
             </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
```